# Flight might be rescheduled, who to trust?

Tags: air-travel, bookings, schedule-change

I have a booking from CPH -> LHR -> JFK -> RDU booked with American Airlines. In the AA app the first leg appears as rescheduled meaning I will miss the long leg. I called AA and they confirm it is rescheduled and offered to find alternatives but because of limited capacity they suggested I call British Airways who is the operator of the first flight. British airways says the plane leaves on time and there is no reschedule. On the airport website the plane is also listed as "on-time", in fact there exists no departure for the rescheduled time.

Should I trust the operator of the actual plane (BA) or the company I made the booking with (AA)?

Details:

- LHR airport website shows the original arrival time.
- all three legs on same itinerary, but i would strongly prefer not arriving delayed
- flight BA811 from CPH->LHR 7:30am 8th of July
- rescheduled time is 9:14am which does not match any departure from CPH

AA app shows 9:14: [image: screenshot showing 9:14]

BA website shows 7:30 [image: screenshot showing 7:30]

Comment: Is this a self-transfer or are both legs booked as one itinerary?

Comment: Which flight is this, on what date?

Comment: Can you see your booking on the BA site? One possibility is that the flight is actually maintained, but they have to switch to a different aircraft with less capacity and you were bumped.

Comment: The Saturday flight usually has an A320neo, but here it’s a 319, not sure if that was the plan from the start or if they switched it. But they still have seats on that flight (not the one on Sunday though). Maybe they bumped people and then there were cancellations so now you could ask to be moved back to it? When you called BA, did you ask about the flight in general or did they look at your actual booking?

Comment: @jcaron they looked at my actual booking.

Comment: 9:14 is a weird departure time. While in the US for instance they schedule flights by the minute, in Europe they are most often scheduled at 5-minute intervals. Are you sure this is the CPH-LHR flight?

Comment: @jcaron added screenshot from AA app

Comment: @jcaron yes can see it on ba website

Comment: The screenshot from the AA app says "depart**ed**" (past tense) at 9:14 AM which is odd.  Might just be a coding error, though.

Comment: Yep the French AA site says “effectif” (actual) for departure and “estimé” (estimated) for arrival, which would be the status for a flight which has actually departed. It looks like they are displaying information from another flight somehow. Flightradar24 doesn’t even have the estimated departure yet for that date (grey dot). FlightAware doesn’t have the “find my plane” button so they don’t have operational info yet either. At this time I would consider the original schedule to hold, the picture should be clearer tomorrow.

Comment: In the first line of your question, did you miss one stop (JFK)? I just went to AAs website and searched for flights this coming saturday. I still have the option to book a flight out of CPH on 7:30am (AA6532), connecting in LHR (to AA101) and JFK (to AA4479). Maybe call again and ask about the mismatch between the app and the booking tool?

Comment: @Sabine yes missed JFK

Comment: BA now have posted an estimated arrival time, 20 minutes early if the flight departs on time. AA still have the funky information, I have no idea where they got that from. Note that your aircraft will actually get to CPH on the last flight this evening and be spend the night there, which minimises the possibility of a delay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is indeed quite odd. I'm suspecting it's some error in AA's scheduling data for code shares. All other websites show the flight on time. Even AA initially does if you do a route search (See below).

[image]

The weirdness only happens if you click through to "check status" where it indeed shows the odd screen that makes little sense including "Flight Status not available" and "departed".

They also didn't bump you to a different flights: there are only 4 flights from CPH to LHR on July 8 and none goes anywhere near that time

[image]

There is 95% chance that AA is wrong, everybody else is right and you will be fine with your original plan. If you want to make sure, you can call AA and insist on resolving this. "BA operates the flight and they say it's on time as booked. Why do you say otherwise? What is the source of this discrepancy?".

Comment: I made the connection without any problems, must have been a glitch, thank you